# Clicking outside textarea makes cursor appear outside of textarea

Tags: html, textarea

I've noticed this behavior for textarea where clicking outside of it, either to the right or left makes a cursor appear outside the text area. Is there anyway to hide the cursor when clicking outside the text area, but keep it inside of it.

Codepen:https://codepen.io/chris123312/pen/GReGBWZ

[Example of the blinking cursor showing outside of the textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrqI7.png)

I can't seem to find anything about this online and chatgpt has provided JS solutions that simply don't work:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Textarea with Hidden Cursor Outside</title>
        <style>
            /* Add your custom styles here */
            .hide-cursor-outside {
                border-radius: 10px; /* Adjust the border radius as needed */
                padding: 10px; /* Optional: Add padding for better visual appearance */
                width: 300px; /* Optional: Set a specific width */
                height: 150px; /* Optional: Set a specific height */
                cursor: text; /* Show the cursor inside the textarea */
            }
            .hide-cursor-outside:focus {
                cursor: default; /* Hide the cursor outside the textarea when focused */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <textarea class="hide-cursor-outside" placeholder="Type something here..."></textarea>
    
        <script>
            // Add event listeners to dynamically toggle the class
            const textarea = document.querySelector('.hide-cursor-outside');
            
            textarea.addEventListener('focus', () => {
                textarea.classList.add('hide-cursor-outside');
            });
    
            textarea.addEventListener('blur', () => {
                textarea.classList.remove('hide-cursor-outside');
            });
        </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a chrome setting problem see fix here: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/77878717/there-is-a-text-cursor-bug-in-my-chrome-that-causes-the-blinking-cursor-to-appear-everywhere-i-click?hl=en

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understood what do you mean but anyway, there is a `CSS` property for the cursor , you can find it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.php)

you can define a `CSS` class for the area where you want the cursor to be hidden like this

```
.no_cursor {cursor: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but here's a workaround to focus the mouse on the textarea whenever the user clicks outside:

```
<body>

    <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Type something here..."></textarea>


<script>
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
  if (!textarea.contains(event.target)) {
    textarea.focus();
  }
});
</script>

</body>
```